# Proxy front-end routes to another domain under the same domain

Tags: javascript, web, proxy, cross-domain

I have a web application which is hosted at `www.shop.com` and another web application hosted at  domain `www.products.shop.com`.

A user comes on the page `www.shop.com` and wants to buy a product. All the information regarding the product purchase is hosted at  domain `www.products.shop.com`. Curently i am redirecting users as from `www.shop.com` to `www.products.shop.com?product_id=8789779`.

This is a bad user experience.

### What i want?

I want to proxy `www.shop.com/products` to `www.products.shop.com`, so `www.shop.com/products?product_id=8789779` will load the page of `www.products.shop.com?product_id=8789779`.

In simple terms i want my  users to be on the same domain/url in the browser.

### Is this possible?

Comment: Can you specify what you use as technologies (nginx / apache, nodejs/php/...)

Comment: @LucasBodin i am using React,Node and in another project NextJs

Comment: Ok and in your server, how are you deploy them, docker, nginx, apache... ?